# Very basic question about the structure of my iPhone game

Tags: iphone, view

I'm making an iPhone game in which I have two main views, the planning stage and the action stage. Both of these will have different graphics etc, but I'll obviously need to pass information between them. I've pretty much finished programming the planning stage, and I know how to switch between views, but I'm a little fuzzy on how exactly I should be setting the whole thing up. Should my SwitchViewController, which handles the switching between the two views, also control the passing of the game state and the game moves between the two views? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably make sense to package all your game information up into a single 'gameState' object, and attach that to your app delegate (or some other 'non transient' object).

If you pass it all back and forth, you can run into problems if you ever change your flow, or add a variable and forget to pass it. This approach avoids both those issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a sharedInstance which will allow you to use data between the two screens.